# odac installation perform prerequisites check does not work

Tags: oracle, windows-10, linked-server, odac

I'm trying to install the `Oracle ODAC 122011` on my `Windows 10 Pro x64` machine but it does not execute the `"Perform Prerequisites Checks"` step.

I am using visual Studio 2107/2019 32 bits..

Here is my PC Properties

[image]

I did a complete uninstall of Oracle following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8450726/how-to-uninstall-completely-remove-oracle-11g-client)articule.

I've tried running the installer as an Administrator.

This is the last window it appears, and it freezes there.

[image]

I see a log file... And i found this..

> WARNING: Active Help Content for OdpGUI.cbxGACODPU do not exist.
>
> Error :Can't find resource for bundle
>   oracle.install.ivw.odac.resource.ContextualHelpResource, key
>   OdpGUI.cbxGACODPU.conciseHelpText WARNING: Active Help Content for
>   TnsGUI.hostname do not exist.
>
> Error :Can't find resource for bundle
>   oracle.install.ivw.odac.resource.ContextualHelpResource, key
>   TnsGUI.hostname.conciseHelpText
>
> WARNING: Active Help Content for TnsGUI.portNumber do not exist.
>
> Error :Can't find resource for bundle
>   oracle.install.ivw.odac.resource.ContextualHelpResource, key
>   TnsGUI.portNumber.conciseHelpText
>
> WARNING: Active Help Content for TnsGUI.connectionalias do not exist.
>
> Error :Can't find resource for bundle
>   oracle.install.ivw.odac.resource.ContextualHelpResource, key
>   TnsGUI.connectionalias.conciseHelpText
>
> WARNING: Active Help Content for TnsGUI.databaseservicename do not
>   exist.
>
> Error :Can't find resource for bundle
>   oracle.install.ivw.odac.resource.ContextualHelpResource, key
>   TnsGUI.databaseservicename.conciseHelpText

In fact, i had installed `ODAC version 122011x64` but something has broken and it stopped working from Visual Studio 2019. It has desappeared from Installed programs. I unistalled it completed and try to installed it again. That is when this problem appeared.

Thanks

Comment: Check your `PATH` environment variable. Perhaps it is tool long. Remove some folder from it, after installation you can add them again. Or run installer from command line, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56792726/install-oracle-client-from-command-line-without-user-interaction

Comment: Thanks.. I just added more descriptions to what happened with your example

Comment: You installed only "SQL Plus" and "Utilities" but you missed the "OraOLEDB" driver. Add it to the `oracle.install.client.customComponents` list. Create an arbitrary response file, there you get a full list of all components with their names.

Comment: Did you try to start the Installer from command line with option `-ignoreSysPrereqs` and/or `-ignorePrereqFailure -skipPrereqs`

Comment: Thanks Wernfied... I want to now if i understood correctly... I should add -ignorePrereqFailure -skipPrereqs because I dont add it... and add OraLLEDB like this...."oracle.install.client.customComponents=oracle.rdbms.util:12.2.0.1.1,oracle.sqlplus:12,OraOLEDB”
Thanks

Comment: Thanks again Wernfried.. I add more description, I have the same error and i found same lines in logs file...

Comment: Correct Name for OLE DB is `oracle.ntoledb:12.2.0.1.0`

Comment: You must also add "Oracle Net" (`oracle.network.client:12.2.0.1.0`), it is a bug in the installer see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30230679/asp-net-application-not-connecting-to-oracle-11g-even-after-installing-oracle-in/51415838#51415838

Comment: Thanks Wernfried, I have a new error with linked server... and still does not appear in Installed Programs... I refreshed the problem... Thanks againg..

Comment: You get an `ORA-` error, i.e. your Oracle installation should be completed. Actually I see your screenshot is Oracle 19. Looks like you mixed Oracle 19.3 and 12.2. Maybe remove any Oracle installation (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8450726/how-to-uninstall-completely-remove-oracle-11g-client) and make a fresh installation from scratch.

Comment: Thanks Wernfried... I have deleted regedit entries.Haven´t find much more. I installed it again and have the same error...what else can it be? I updated the question.Thanks again

Comment: It is getting difficult. Can you connect with sqlplus?

Comment: Hi Wernfried, I have installed SQDeveloper64W, I can connect without any problems..

Comment: SQLDeveloper is based on Java and works completely different, thus it is no reference for installation. What about sqlplus? When you see two different Oracle folders then obviously you did not remove them properly. Check again with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8450726/how-to-uninstall-completely-remove-oracle-11g-client

Comment: Some time ago a wrote a small application which tests all Oracle drivers/providers, see https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1066432/Verify-Oracle-Client-Installation perhaps it will show what is working and what is not working.

Comment: Thanks again Wernfried... I made a PC full clean. Have no problems with linked server but still have the initial problem. Nice test application.. I test it and show me same errors I already post it... thanks again...

Comment: Do you run application in Visual Studio in 32-bit or 64-bit?

Comment: it is 32 bits...is that the problem? if I have in 64 everythings work fine? or it another issue? I need to install ODAC 32 bits or Visual 64 bits?

Comment: When your application is running in 64-bit then the Oracle has to be also the 64-bit version (or both must be 32-bit) If you like to install both then follow this instruction: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24104210/badimageformatexception-this-will-occur-when-running-in-64-bit-mode-with-the-32#24120100

Comment: Thanks Wernfried... I did a new post here "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58261522/odac-setup-error-ins-50013-oracle-developer-tools-for-visual-studio-net-error" i am facing a new problem with odac 32 bits... thank for helping..